# Comparing table data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, optimization, compare

I need to identify which records are missing in a table taking another table for comparison.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE tableA.id NOT IN (SELECT tableB.id FROM tableB)
```

It normally works when the data is small of course but tableA and tableB both have over 400k records and the process gets stuck, is there a more optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Joins are usually faster than IN and NOT IN clause. Try this:

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA left join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id
WHERE tableB.id is null
```

Comment: You'll need two queries if you want missing rows in either table.